# Is this proof mathematically correct?

Tags: solution-verification

Is the following proof technically correct? I am aware that it might not seem typical, but me and my math teacher did not find why it isn't correct.

> In a triangle ABC, given AB=AC, prove ∠B=∠C. (This is not a textbook problem, I created it out of my mind.)

In ∆ABC and ∆ACB:

```
AB=AC
∠A=∠A
AC=AB
```

∴ ∆ABC Is Congruent To ∆ACB

∴ ∠B=∠C

**I am aware that there are alternatives.** I can construct another triangle that is congruent to ∆ABC, in that order, and then prove it congruent to ∆ACB, in that order, but that adds complexity to my proof.

Comment: So basically you are creating a similarity between the triangle and a reflected version of itself (using SAS postulate)? I think that works. The way you state it seems like you are just renaming the same triangle though. I might add primes to indicate the difference between the two triangles. Ex: A vs. A'

Comment: This is [Pappus' proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pons_asinorum#Pappus) of the "Pons Asinorum" (aka, the Isosceles Triangle Theorem). ... BTW: If you want us to see your message to your instructor, please just enter the specific text of that message. Throwing a bunch of JSON on screen and requiring the reader to take it to another site to make any sense of it isn't helpful.

Comment: @KevinS I am in China and China assumes if you say two triangles are congruent angle A corresponds to angle D if you write ABC ~= DEF

Comment: Thank you @Blue and I think Blue is a good name...

Comment: "Mathematically correct" is a very long way of saying "correct"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is mathematically correct.